# Reading in single str column with loadtxt

Tags: numpy, scipy

I have the file called `mda_bk-adds-gro.inp`:

```
# -*- mode:python -*-
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, walp_fixed.gro
0.5, 0.5, 0.4, walp.gro
```

I think I'll read the numbers and the the word separately. I've succeded in parsing the numbers:

```
loadtxt('mda_bk-adds-gro.inp', comments='#', delimiter=',', usecols=(0,1,2))
```

But can't read in just words:

```
loadtxt('mda_bk-adds-gro.inp', comments='#', delimiter=',', dtype=[('fileName', '|S100')], usecols=(3))
```

it gives an error:

```
 TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

So my question is - how do I read the forth column with `loadtxt` provided the column is `str`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the `TypeError` because `(3)` is not a tuple, but just a parenthesized `int`-typed expression. Try `usecols=(3,)` instead.

See the comments at [this issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue2817) for an explanation why this is so.

Comment: `loadtxt('mda_bk-adds-gro.inp', comments='#', delimiter=',', dtype=[('fileName', '|S100')], usecols=(3,))` gives `list index out of range`. So that was it. Can You please recommend me something regarding the new error?

Comment: hm... I wounder then where might I be mistaken.