# usecols in loadtxt

Tags: python, numpy

I founds this error in multiple question but it is not fixed or explained
Ex. [Reading in single str column with loadtxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742156/reading-in-single-str-column-with-loadtxt)

I have a problem with the following line (`import numpy as np`)

```
    symbols = np.loadtxt('filename.csv',
               dtype={'names': ('ticker', 'year', 'month','day'),
                      'formats': ('S10','i4','i2','i2')},
                delimiter=',',skiprows=1, usecols=(0,))
```

with following data

```
ticker  year    month   day
GPD.TO  2010    8   16
HAO.V   2010    8   16
RDS.V   2010    8   16
MD.V    2010    8   16
```

It gives me a

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When I run that line without `usecols` it works fine and returns all 4 columns fine.

I looked at many other questions on google and Stackoverflow but this isnt answered

Comment: A side comment here: you do realize that `i4` and `i2` mean 4 bytes and 2 bytes, not 4 characters and 2 characters, and 2 bytes is enough to hold a year (anything up to 32767), and 1 byte is enough to hold a month or day (anything up to 127), right?

Comment: Thanks! i4 and i2 did seem odd and didnt follow usual designation for number, i was feeling fishy about that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `usecols = (0,)` with `np.loadtxt` then you must change the `dtype` to match:

```
import numpy as np
symbols = np.loadtxt('filename.csv',
                     dtype={'names': ('ticker', ),
                            'formats': ('S10',)},
                     delimiter=',',
                     skiprows=1,
                     usecols=(0,)
                     )
print(symbols)
```

with `filename.csv`:

```
ticker,year,month,day
GPD.TO,2010,8,16
HAO.V,2010,8,16
RDS.V,2010,8,16
MD.V,2010,8,16
```

yields

```
[('GPD.TO',) ('HAO.V',) ('RDS.V',) ('MD.V',)]
```

---

Alternatively, with `np.genfromtxt` you do not need to change `dtype`:

```
symbols = np.genfromtxt('filename.csv',
                        dtype={'names': ('ticker', 'year', 'month','day'),
                               'formats': ('S10','i4','i2','i2')},                        
                        delimiter=',',
                        skiprows=1,
                        usecols=(0,)
                        )
```

works as well.

Comment: This is correct, but I think it needs to be a bit clearer. He already had the right `dtype` for column 0 (`S10`); the problem is that his `dtype` has a different shape than the result he expects—he's specifying a `dtype` for a 4-column array, and then trying to read only 1 column into it.